# How to get data from a cnc controller and store it in a database?

Tags: database, serial-port

I am thinking of using vb.net and fetch data from a cnc controller (FANUC) which has FOCAS libraries, it supports vb.net. Please let me know how to get the data from it and store it in a database wamp server

Comment: Can you please tell a suffice and descriptive aim for what you want to do.

Comment: Let us know the model and provide an API document if possible. Thanks.

Comment: to get data from the controller , like number of parts produced, machine power on time power off time.

Comment: controller name - FANUC 0i -

Comment: i am having trouble, adding reference in vb , i.e., to add the fwlib64.dll file to vb project .. help me with the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry my example is for the 32bit implementation, but the 64 bit should parallel it)

Please take a look at your Fanuc Focus API CD.
You should find a directory like this:

> \Fanuc Focas2 Drivers & Libraries V4.20\Fwlib\Dot NET sample

In that directory there will be the file:

fwlib32.vb

Add this file to your project.  It will define all the possible function imports that you can use in Focas (Later you can trip this down of course, but to get started learning this, just use this file)

Comment: Can you show me a sample code to get the machine's power on/off time ? 
so i can understand it better ..
thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Please check the MTConnect adapter and the Fanuc-MTConnect-Agent.

After you got data by the adapter, you could use vb.net to do the next.

Fanuc adapter in cpp:

https://github.com/mtconnect/adapter/tree/master/fanuc

you can find the compiled Fanuc adapter here:

https://www.trakhound.com/downloads [MTConnect Agent for Fanuc]

and open source hosted on GitHub for MTConnect Agent for Fanuc:

https://github.com/TrakHound/Fanuc-MTConnect-Agent

Comment: Would you please explain or summarize what contents are in the link briefly? That is better to answer about the question. :)